# Changing color range in a d3 reusable donut chart depending on the number of data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using this reusable chart as a base: http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9368297

I am trying to find a way to change the color range set based on the number of arcs (size), without having to rewrite the main donut().

For example, one donuts getData size would be 2 (having the colors green and gray), and another donuts getData size would be 3 (now remove gray and change colors to green, red, and yellow).

I cannot remove the colors from donut() it seems, so I tried to find a way to maybe associate colors with specific data points, but I cannot figure that out with this template.

Edit: Specifying code changes already done.

I have 6 different getData functions, roughly as follows:

```
var getFirstDonutData = function () {
    var size = 2;
    var data = [firstData1, firstData2];
    var text = "";
    d3.select("#data");
    return data;
};

var getSecondDonutData = function () {
    var size = 3;
    var data = [secondData1, secondData2, secondData3];
    var text = "";
    d3.select("#data");
    return data;
};

var getThirdDonutData = function () {
    var size = 2;
    var data = [thirdData1, thirdData2];
    var text = "";
    d3.select("#data");
    return data;
};
```

Then 6 different of the following:

```
var twoPointDonut = donut()
              .$el(d3.select("#twoPointDonut "))
              .data(getFirstDonutData ())
              .render();

var threePointDonut = donut()
              .$el(d3.select("#threePointDonut "))
              .data(getSecondDonutData ())
              .render();

var otherTwoPointDonut = donut()
              .$el(d3.select("#otherTwoPointDonut "))
              .data(getThirdDonutData ())
              .render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fill of the arc is determined by the `color()` function on this line:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.key); });
```

Instead of using a function, we can pick from an array of colors based on the index. Modify the above line to read:

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; });
```

Now we need to change the list of available colors based on the number of data points (number of keys in the data object). Above the `color()` function, add:

```
var dataSize = Object.keys(getData()).length
var color = d3.scale.category20(); // This line was already here
```

Finally, we need to change the `color` variable from a function to an array. The array will vary based on the `dataSize`, so a `switch` statement works great here. Replace the color definition:

```
var color;

switch (dataSize) {
  case 2:
    color = ['green' , 'gray'];
    break;
  case 3:
    color = ['green', 'red', 'yellow'];
    break;
}
```

This will give you green and gray when there are only two datapoints; and green, red, and yellow when there are 3 data points. You can add more `case`s for more amounts of data points.

[Everything in one JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/08vxkw77/1/)

With two data points:

[image: Donut chart showing two data points]

With three data points:

[image: Donut chart showing two data points]

---

**Edit:** Since you are using more than one chart and set of data on the same page, you will need to move this whole block to *inside* the `Object.render()` function:

```
var dataSize = Object.keys(getData()).length;
var color;

switch (dataSize) {
  case 2:
    color = ['green' , 'gray'];
    break;
  case 3:
    color = ['green', 'red', 'yellow'];
    break;
}
```

and then change the `dataSize` variable to get the length of the passed in `data` object's keys:

```
var dataSize = Object.keys(data).length;
```

[New complete JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/08vxkw77/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have some other concerns though and updated the question. Pretty much, I was creating separate getData()'s to accommodate individual donuts, since the data comes from specific variables. Since the main donut() is using "getData" specifically, I would be unable to create multiples the way I am currently. I tried passing the data in as another array, but then the donut couldn't see it in time I guess and failed to load it.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Sorry if this is a bit beyond scope, but do you know if there any drawbacks to having that information within the render function?

Comment: One drawback is that the `color` array is now more narrow in scope. If other functions call for it, they may not be able to see it anymore since it is inside the `render` function. I didn't look at the code too close, but I think it is being called onmouseover, so that will need to be addressed (although it doesn't affect functionality as it is right now).

Comment: And also, if you ever pass data with any other number of data points besides 2 or 3, it will error unless you add cases for them. You may want to set some safe default in the switch statement, as well.